# Write a loop that prints out all the words ending with 's'

Tags: ada

Basically, in this code, I have created an array of strings that hold 5 elements. Then by using a loop, I should print out all the words ending with 's' and even their line numbers(1 to 5). How should I write the for loop(or any other type of loops/recursion) for this code?

```
with Ada.Text_IO;                    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;            use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;           use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with  Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO.Unbounded_IO;

Procedure Line_Words is
type data is array (1..5) of Unbounded_String;
A: data;

begin
A(1):= To_Unbounded_String("Peas"); 
A(2):= To_Unbounded_String("Bone");
A(3):= To_Unbounded_String("As");
A(4):= To_Unbounded_String("Sos");
A(5):= To_Unbounded_String("Found"); 

for I in data'Range loop
?????????????????? -- A loop that prints out all the words ending with 's' and their line-numbers.

end Line_words ;
```

Comment: Aside from your untidy lack of formatting, you seem to have enough grasp of Ada that you should at least be able to include the `end loop;`. Then, within the loop, you have to decide whether to print anything; that will be an `if` statement, involving the last character of the array element. As it stands, you haven’t shown any effort in the area of the problem you’re asking about.

Comment: note you can initialiase data inplace: `A: data := (To_Unbounded_String("One"), To_Unbounded_String("Two"));` which is especially useful because now you can let the compiler sort out what size it will be based on that initialisation if you change data to be: `type data is array (Positive range <>) of Unbounded_String;`

Answer (score 3):

Look at the package Ada.Strings.Unbounded. It contains a function named Tail which returns an unbounded string.

```
function Tail (Source : in Unbounded_String;
                  Count  : in Natural;
                  Pad    : in Character := Space)
      return Unbounded_String;
```

If you pass your unbounded string as the Source parameter and pass 1 as the Count parameter the function will return an unbounded string containing only the last character in your Source unbounded string.

You cannot print out a line number for your array of unbounded strings. You can print out the array index number for each unbounded string ending in 's'. Think how you will compare the return value of Tail with the unbounded string created from To_Unbounded_String("s").